# What is the difference in meaning betweee the structure "not...or," "neither...nor, " and "not...nor/neither"?

Tags: grammar, difference

Is there any difference in meaning between the following sentences?

> My tablet **isn't** good **or** bad.
>
> My tablet is **neither** good **nor** bad.
>
> My tablet **isn't** good, **nor** is it bad.
>
> My tablet **isn't** good **neither** is it bad.

I cannot see any difference, but it feels to me that the third and the forth sentences sound more emphatic. If all the senteces have exactly the same meaning, then which ones are more formal?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, I think they all mean the same. However, the first sentence, using "nor" instead of "or" is more correct. So, "My tablet isn't good nor bad."

Regarding formality, sentences 2-4 sound more formal while the first sentence is the least formal.

Comment: Common misconception, but technically no. "Nor" is only used with "neither" and in constructions like "nor is it x". When just stating that something isn't either of two things, "or" is correct.